# Parsing and executing a simple shell script

Tags: c, parsing, shell

I'm writing a simple shell and want to parse and execute a simple shell script.

```
PAGER=more
if type less > /dev/null;then PAGER=less; fi
echo $PAGER
printenv|grep $1|$PAGER
```

The above sets a pager and greps the environment variables for a variable.

I run the script from my shell after I start it:

```
$ ./shell 
'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin.
$ ../checkenv.sh GNOME
20470: executing ../checkenv.sh
less
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
INSTANCE=GNOME
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
(END)


20470: executed
$
```

Looks like it's "working" but what do you think of the code?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool donotrun = false;
    struct sigaction new_action, old_action;
    hashtable_t *hashtable = ht_create(65536);
    /* Set up the structure to specify the new action. */
    new_action.sa_handler = termination_handler;
    sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGHUP, &new_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGTERM, &new_action, NULL);

    bool background = false;
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    char *cvalue = NULL;
    const char *commandFile = NULL;

    while (1) {
        index = 0;
        i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "pc:fvh",
                        options, &index);
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        switch (i) {
            case 'p': {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            case 'v': {
                printf("sh OpenShell version 0.1(a)\n");
                printf("Version: %s\n", VERSION);

              //  printf ("%s / %s / %s / %s\n",
                //         program_name, version,
                  //       build_date, build_git_sha);


                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'h': {
                usage();
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'c': {
                cvalue = optarg;
                command(cvalue, hashtable, background);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }

            case 'f': {
                /*
                 * Execute commands from file.
                 * This is used for osh script files.
                 * The quiet flag is also set.
                 */
                //if ((argc != 1) || commandFile)
                    //usage();
                //quietFlag = TRUE;
                printf("case f\n");
                //commandFile = *argv++;

                argc--;
                *argv++;
                *argv++;
                readFile(*argv++, argc, argv, hashtable, background);
                //free(line);
                exit(0);

                //break;
            }

            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'c')
                    fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint (optopt))
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                            optopt);
            default: {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    getPath();
    char *copy = "";

    for (; ;) {
        bool scanning = true;
        while (scanning) {
            char *line = NULL;
            line = readline("$ ");
            if (line == NULL) {
                /* No more lines, so exit the loop. */
                break;
            }
            if (line)
                copy = strdup(line);

            if (line && !strstr(line, "for") && !strstr(line, "==") && !strstr(line, "if") && strstr(line, "=")) {
                donotrun = true;
                char str[128];
                char *ptr;
                strcpy(str, line);
                strtok_r (str, "=", &ptr);
                ht_set(hashtable, str, ptr);
            }

            if (!scanning)
                break;

            if (commandFile!=NULL || !isatty(fileno(stdin))) {
                *argv++;
                readFile(*argv++, argc, argv, hashtable, background);
                free(line);
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                if (!donotrun) {
                    line = strrep(line, " | ", "|");
                    line = strrep(line, " |", "|");
                    background = testFn2(line);
                    if (background)
                        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
                    command(line, hashtable, background);
                }
                donotrun = false;
                add_history(copy);

            }
            free(copy);
        }
    }
    //  ParseFree(pParser, free);FIXME: where should this go?
    return 0;
/*
 * Read commands from the specified file.
 * A null name pointer indicates to read from stdin.
 */
static int readFile(const char *name, int argc, char ** argv, hashtable_t *hashtable, bool background) {
    FILE *fp;
    int cc;
    bool ttyFlag;
    char buf[CMD_LEN];
    int r = 0;

    if (sourceCount >= MAX_SOURCE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many source files\n");

        return 1;
    }

    fp = stdin;
    printf("name %s\n", name);

    if (name) {
        fp = fopen(name, "r");

        if (fp == NULL) {
            perror(name);

            return 1;
        }
    }

    sourcefiles[sourceCount++] = fp;

    ttyFlag = isatty(fileno(fp));
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (ttyFlag)
            showPrompt();

        if (intFlag && !ttyFlag && (fp != stdin)) {
            fclose(fp);
            sourceCount--;

            return 1;
        }
        if (fgets(buf, CMD_LEN - 1, fp) == NULL) {
            if (ferror(fp) && (errno == EINTR)) {
                clearerr(fp);

                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        cc = strlen(buf);
        if (buf[cc - 1] == '\n')
            cc--;

        while ((cc > 0) && isBlank(buf[cc - 1]))
            cc--;

        buf[cc] = '\0';
        //printf("buf %s\n", argv[0]);
        strreplace(buf, "$1", argv[0]);

        //printf("arg %s\n", ++argv);

        if (strstr(buf, "=")) {
            char str[128];
            char *ptr;
            strcpy(str, buf);
            strtok_r (str, "=", &ptr);
            ht_set(hashtable, str, ptr);
        }

        //printf("the command is %s\n", buf);
        r = command(buf, hashtable, background);
        i++;
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        perror("Reading command line");

        if (fp == stdin)
            exit(1);
    }

    clearerr(fp);

    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);

    sourceCount--;

    return r;
}


/*
 * Parse and execute one null-terminated command line string.
 * This breaks the command line up into words, checks to see if the
 * command is an alias, and expands wildcards.
 */
int command(char *cmd, hashtable_t *hashtable, bool background) {

    const char *endCmd;
    char cmdName[CMD_LEN];
    freeChunks();
    //printf("cmd %s\n", cmd);
    /*
     * Skip leading blanks.
     */
    if (cmd) {
        while (isBlank(*cmd))
            cmd++;
        /*
         * If the command is empty or is a comment then ignore it.
         */

        if ((*cmd == '\0') || (*cmd == '#'))
            return 0;
        /*
         * Look for the end of the command name and then copy the
         * command name to a buffer so we can null terminate it.
         */
        endCmd = cmd;

        while (*endCmd && !isBlank(*endCmd))
            endCmd++;

        memcpy(cmdName, cmd, endCmd - cmd);
        cmdName[endCmd - cmd] = '\0';
        /*
         * Expand simple environment variables
         */
        while (!strstr(cmd, "((") && strstr(cmd, "$("))
            expandVariable((char *) cmd, hashtable);

        /*
        * Expand POSIX variable expansion e g $ echo $str
        */
        while (!strstr(cmd, "((") && strstr(cmd, "$")) {
            if (!expand_parameter((char *) cmd, hashtable))
                break;
        }
        /*
        * Expand POSIX arithemtic expansion
        */
        while (strstr(cmd, "$((")) { /* bug: assignment as conditional */
            if ((cmd = expand_calc((char *) cmd)))
                break;
        }

        while (strstr(cmd, "if")) { /* bug: assignment as conditional */
            if ((cmd = if_execute((char *) cmd, hashtable)))
                break;
        }

        /*
          * Now look for the command in the builtin table, and execute
          * the command if found.
          */
        int * reti;
        if (exec_builtin(reti, cmd)) {
            return 0;
        }
        /*
         * The command is not a built-in, so run the program along
         * the PATH list.
         */
        return run_cmd(cmd, background);
    }
    else return 0;
}

int run_cmd(char *cmd, bool background) {

    char buffer[2];
    buffer[0] = '|';
    buffer[1] = '\0';
    struct str_list *chunks = list_split(cmd, buffer);
    struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);
    if (pipe == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < chunks->pipes; i++) {
        pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char **) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
        if (pipe[i].data == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
        }
        int j = 0;
        pipe[i].size = chunks[i].size;
        for (j = 0; j < chunks[i].size; j++) {
            if (chunks[i].argv[j] == NULL) {
                chunks[i].argv[j] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            pipe[i].option = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
            if (pipe[i].option == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
            }
            pipe[i].data[j] = strdup(chunks[i].argv[j]);
            if (pipe[i].data[j] == NULL) {
                perror("strdup");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            * pipe[i].option = * chunks[i].option;
        }
        pipe[i].data[j] = '\0';
    }
    int status = execute_pipeline(chunks->pipes, pipe, background);
    return status;
}


int execute_pipeline(int n, struct pipeline *pipe, bool background) {
    // background = false;
    int status = 0;
    pid_t pid = -2;
    if (n > -1)
        pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* spawn(cmd);*/
        fork_pipeline(n, pipe);
    }
    /*
     * We are the parent process.
     * Wait for the child to complete.
     */

    if (!background) {
        while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: executed\n", (int) pid);
    }
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

        return -1;
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```

The grammar (with [lemon parser](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/)) is:

```
%include
{
#include "types.h"
#include "openshell.h"
#include "assert.h"
}
%syntax_error { fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error\n"); }
%token_type { struct SToken* }
%type expr { int }

%nonassoc EQEQ NOTEQ SET LARGER SMALLER.
%left FOR WHILE OUTR IF.
%left PLUS MINUS.
%left TIMES DIVIDE THEN SEMICOLON.

program ::= expr(A). { setresult(A);  }

expr(A) ::= expr(B) PLUS expr(C). {A = B + C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) MINUS expr(C). {A = B - C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) TIMES expr(C). {A = B * C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) EQEQ expr(C). { if(B==C) {A=1;} else A=0;setresult2(A);}
expr(A) ::= expr(B) NOTEQ expr(C). {if(B==C) {A=0;} else A=1;}
expr(A) ::= expr(B) LARGER expr(C). {if(B>C) {A=1;} else A=0;}
expr(A) ::= expr(B) SMALLER expr(C). {if(B<C) {A=1;} else A=0;}
expr(A) ::= TRUE. { A=1; }
expr(A) ::= FALSE. { A=0; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) SET expr(C).  {A=C;B=C;}
expr(A) ::= FOR LPAR expr(B) SEMICOLON expr(C) SEMICOLON expr(D) RPAR expr(E). {A = D*B*E*C+1; /* $((for ( 1 == 1 ; 2 == 2 ; 3 == 3 ) 55)) */}
expr(A) ::= WHILE LPAR expr(B) RPAR expr(C).
{
while (B) { printf("%d", C);
}
A=C;printf("\n");
}
expr(A) ::= expr(B) DIVIDE expr(C).
{
    if (C != 0)
    {
        A = B / C;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "divide by 0");
    }
}
expr(A) ::= LPAR expr(B) RPAR. { A = B; }
expr(A) ::= INTEGER(B).
{
/* printf("the result = %s\n", B->token); */
    A = B->value;
    /*printf("Passed argument: %s\n", B->token);*/
}
expr(A) ::= expr(B) SEMICOLON. { A=B;  }

expr(A) ::= IF expr(B) SEMICOLON THEN expr(C) SEMICOLON FI. {  setresult2(B); A=C; } /* if [ 1 == 1 ];then echo FOO; fi ;fi; if [ true ];then echo FOO; fi if type less > /dev/null;then echo FOO; fi */

expr(A) ::= command . {  A=1; setresult(A);  }

command ::= FILENAME argumentList .{   }
command ::= FILENAME .

argumentList ::= argument .
argument ::= ARGUMENT .
argument ::= FILENAME .{  }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) OUTR FILENAME.{  A=B; }
```

The entire project is available from [my github](https://github.com/montao/openshell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is lots of small stuff that muddies seeing the overall flow.

My apologizes for only a primarily low-level review.

1. Drop though cases.  The code *appears* to be OK. Yet it looks like it might be missing a `break;` at the end of `case '?'`.  Recommend to add a comment at the end of a case that intentionally lacks a `break`, `return`,etc.

   ```
       case '?':
           if (optopt == 'c')
               fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
           else if (isprint (optopt))
               fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
           else
               fprintf(stderr,
                       "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                       optopt);

           // Add comment
           // Drop though

       default: {
           return 1;
       }
   ```
2. Remove debug code

   ```
           printf("sh OpenShell version 0.1(a)\n");
           printf("Version: %s\n", VERSION);

         //  printf ("%s / %s / %s / %s\n",
           //         program_name, version,
             //       build_date, build_git_sha);
   ```
3. Obviously missing include files and other code needed before `main()`.

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       bool donotrun = false;
       struct sigaction new_action, old_action;
       hashtable_t *hashtable = ht_create(65536);
   ```
4. Inconsistent indentation. An `if()` without `{}` is tolerable, yet not preferred, yet then code breaks a line that would look fine as one.  Suggest re-formating.

   ```
   // if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
   //     sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action, NULL);
   // ...
   // i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "pc:fvh",
   //                 options, &index);

   if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN) {
       sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action, NULL);
   }
   ...
   i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "pc:fvh", options, &index);
   ```
5. Inconsistent formating in `switch statement concerning blank lines.  This and other parts hints that OP is not using an automated formatter.  Save time.  Use an automated formatter.  Often these are incorporated within a design environment.  Stand alone ones exist.  Avoid manual formatting.

   ```
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       }
       case 'h': {
           usage();
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       }
       case 'c': {
           cvalue = optarg;
           command(cvalue, hashtable, background);
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }

       case 'f': {
   ```
6. `getPath();` is undefined, naked and uncommented.  Certainly such a call could return an error, one that is not handled here.
7. Buffer over flow potential.  There is nothing special about 128.  Code needs protection/re-work.

   ```
           char str[128];
           strcpy(str, line);  // Unsafe
   ```
8. For array indexing use `size_t`.

   ```
           // int cc;
           size_t cc;

           cc = strlen(buf);
   ```
9. Avoid a hacker exploit.  `buf[0]` could be 0 and then `buf[cc - 1]` is UB.  Instead test.

   ```
   if (fgets(buf, CMD_LEN - 1, fp) == NULL) {
   ...
   cc = strlen(buf);
   //if (buf[cc - 1] == '\n')
   if (cc > 0 && buf[cc - 1] == '\n')
   ```
10. Simplification

    ```
    //char buffer[2];
    //buffer[0] = '|';
    //buffer[1] = '\0';
    char buffer[] = "|";
    ```
11. Avoid allocation by size of type.  Instead by the size of the referenced variable.  This post does not show `struct pipeline`.  OTOH, with the right code, we can have less need for it.  BTW, pedantic point: good to do allocation math leading with `sizeof` as that insures math at least at `size_t` width.  Consider `malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size * sizeof *(pipe[i].data))` *could* overflow the `BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size` first done in that order.

    ```
     // pipe[i].option = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
     pipe[i].option = malloc(sizeof *(pipe[i].option) * 10);

     // pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char **) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
     pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof *(pipe[i].data) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
    ```
12. Allocation test good, but needs an exit.  Good to test, but then what?  Suggest returning a failure code too.  IMO, better to include some diagnostic info like `__LINE__`, `__FUNC__`, etc.

    ```
    if (pipe == NULL) {
        // fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
       fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed! %d\n", __LINE__);
        // add
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ```
13. Some systems have a multitude of special integer types.  Rather than guess at their width and potentially truncate, just go for the largest supported on printing

    ```
     // fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld:\n", (long) pid);
     fprintf(stderr, "pid %lld:\n", (long long) pid);
     // or
     fprintf(stderr, "pid %jd:\n", (intmax_t) pid);
    ```
14. Unclear if the result of `list_split()` is *always* `chunks->pipes > 0`.  If it could be 0, then `malloc(0)` returning `NULL` is *not* a sign of OOM.

    ```
    struct str_list *chunks = list_split(cmd, buffer);
    struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);
    // if (pipe == NULL) {
    if (pipe == NULL && chunks->pipes > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
    }
    ```
15. Code is certainly wrong - passing an unknown value in `reti` to `exec_builtin()`.  With that - code is broken - review done.

    ```
    int * reti;
    if (exec_builtin(reti, cmd)) {
        return 0;
    }
    ```